# Png image is not loading corretly. Using stbi_load() opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, stb-image

So I have this problem: I am loading image with `stbi_load()` and then creating texture with `glTexImage2D()`. When I load `.jpg` image, then everything works normaly, but when I load `.png`, then the drawn image is black, where it should be transparent. Here is picture:
[pictureOfWronglyDrawnPng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1qgS.png)

Here is code I have used:

Frist I set texture parametri:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Then I load the picture:

```
m_data = stbi_load(pathToTexture, &m_height, &m_width, &m_nrChannels, RGBA ? STBI_rgb : STBI_rgb_alpha);
```

And lastly I create texture and genarte mipMap:

```
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, RGBA ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA, m_height, m_width, 0, RGBA ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

`RGBA` is bool that i set when i create Texture class

Here is also my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 OutFrag;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 TexPos;

void main()
{
    OutFrag = vec4(color, 1.0)  * texture(tex, TexPos);
}
```

Does anyone know, why is the texture drawing incorrectly?

Comment: Look closely at `RGBA ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA`

Answer (score 0):

As Alan has mentioned in a comment `RGBA ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA` doesn't quiet look right. If `RGBA` bool is set, don't you want to enable RGBA? if so this should be `RGBA ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB` instead of `RGBA ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA`.

This will evaluate to `GL_RGBA` if the RGBA flag is set and would evaluate to `GL_RGB` otherwise. Your current code does the opposite. Of course it could be the case that this inverse behavior was intentional though seems unlikely judging by the flag name `RGBA`.

Also you might want to enable blending as well.

Try adding these two lines

`glEnable(GL_BLEND);`

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`